# Moving a graph by its x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I have a program that plots some graph from data I have on CSV file (later would be extended to 4 CSV files as sources).
I have 2 questions:

1. how can I move the graph to the left a bit? (such that the first value of the x axis would be 1, that is 10^0 and I would not have that straigt line as values from the axis intersection to the 10^0)
2. How can I put some text instead of the value I see on the right hand side (its the first value in the column of data: 0.031249....)?

Here is the graph:

[image: graph]

And here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/mse_loss_noisy_image.csv")
df = pd.concat([df1], axis=1)
df.plot(logx=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move graph to the left:

```
ax = df.plot(logx=True)
ax.set_xlim(1,1000)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I need to do it via pandas.
I already got the answer for the labeling:
df1.columns = ['a']

But now I'm trying to move the x axis....

Comment: Ah sorry, to move  the x axis maybe you can try  ax= df.plot(logx=True) and  ax.set_xlim(1,1000)  . if this solves your problem i can edit my answer.

Comment: It worked! thanks!!
Do you also know how can I adjust the y labels to be 0.00 to 0.08 with jumps of 0.02 (5 values overall)?

Comment: please try:   ax.set_ylim(0.00,0.08,0.02)

Comment: "import numpy" then set your y axis limit with  "ax.set_ylim(0.00, 0.08)"  then create your tick interval with "y_ticks = np.arange(0.00, 0.08, 0.02) and finally set it with "ax.set_yticks(y_ticks)"    Hope that helps.